# Print PHP array structure

Tags: php, arrays, printing, structure, echo

I am new to PHP and stuck here, I want to view the values and structure of $_ITEM array. I have following php code.

```
    $this->dtgItem->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Item', '<?= $_ITEM->ShortDescription ?>', 'CssClass="dtg_column_print"'));
            $this->dtgItem->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Code', '<?= $_ITEM->RenderBarcode() ?>', 'Width=200', 'CssClass="dtg_column_print"', 'HtmlEntities=false'));
        $this->dtgItem->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Qty', '<?= $_ITEM->Quantity ?>', 'Width=100','CssClass=dtg_column_print'));
        $this->dtgItem->AddColumn(new QDataGridColumn('Receipt #', '<?= $_ITEM->ReceiptNumber ?>', 'CssClass=dtg_column_print'));
```

I want to view structure of the $_ITEM Array.

I have tried following but it does not work.

```
echo "<pre style=\"font-size:12px;\">".print_r($_ITEM,true)."</pre>";
```

I would appreciate if someone can help to figure this out.

Thanks

- Imran

Comment: You can use `print_r($_ITEM)` OR `var_dump($_ITEM)` to view the structure and value of `$_ITEM`

Comment: tried that and I get Undefined variable: _ITEM message

Comment: [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) When the second parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it. This is useful if you want to store it in a variable and print later.

Comment: can you give exact code to write, how can I print values of $_ITEM

Comment: in your code `'<?= $_ITEM->Quantity ?>'` is a string. I don't know if there is a meaning for `$_ITEM` in QDataGridColumn. but there is no such variable in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```
echo "<pre style='font-size:12px;'>";
print_r($_ITEM); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: does not work, i get Undefined variable: _ITEM message

Comment: That means you have not initialized `$_ITEM` variable anywhere and using it. If you are printing the variable in the same php page, then if you defined it properly, it should show something, even if blank array.